# How to specify unprintable as the key-value delimiter in Hadoop streaming

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

att. I am using stream.map.output.field.separator= to specify the delimiter

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of anyway you can pass in a non-printable character via the -Dkey=value generic options syntax, but you should be able to amend the code to allow special interpretation of escape-like codes:

- http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.0.3/src/contrib/streaming/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/streaming/PipeMapper.java?view=markup - line 78 is where the separator is read from the job conf

Amending this code, you could detect a prefix like `&#x` for example and treat the trailing characters as hex-encoded, so tab could be passed as `-Dstream.map.output.field.separator=&#x09`.